# fetch coordinates from CLLocationManager

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I have added map view and added required map-kit frame work and core location framework, using iOS6, i added these methods, but not getting current coordinates so that i can display the indicator for gps tracking.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"first time -- locations.count = %d", locations.count);

    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) > 15.0) {
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
            location.coordinate.latitude,
            location.coordinate.longitude);
    }
}
```

It's giving me default value (latitude +37.785834, longitude -122.406417) of map, not the current location of my place.

Comment: If you are trying it out in the simulator, you will get the default values. You have to run the code on your device to get the actual co-ordinate values.

Comment: thank you very much Vidya Murthy, one more thing , i have reading reywenderlich tutorial, he downloaded some files to show the street or path in google map for tracing using gps, is that required .

Comment: i like to join you for further discussion, my gmail id  rameshrajput007@gmail.com give your linking mail

Comment: @terminator This is very Easy man. You don't know that much also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Vidya, to get actual values of your location, you will need to try on a real device. To test if you set up correctly, choose some location from the simulator, and see if the coordinates reflect the changes.

[image]

Comment: thans you, should i required to add other files to show tracing path on device using gps .

Comment: What do you mean tracing path? If you mean to show it on a map, you can take a look at `MapKit` framework for iOS.

Comment: i am implementing GPS in my project that calculate the walking path from current location to destination location, and also shows the path.